# How to make navigation drawer without actionbar

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am trying to implement navigation drawer without `ActionBar`.

[image]

There is a small layout and inside it there is a button.
When the button is clicked then the navigation drawer will open. The navigation drawer will be under the button.
How can i implement this in android???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Navigation drawer without actionbar, android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30961326/navigation-drawer-without-actionbar-android)

Answer (score 0):

Define your xml like this and you are done

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp" // static height for view or keep it dimen.xml
        android:background="#21ef70"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Click"
            android:id="@+id/button2" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<!-- Listview to display navigation menu -->
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp" // same margin as of layout
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: And if you want it to be under the green layout, just put a padding to the list and a transparent background.

Comment: @StephaneMathis hey I already given margin from top to listview?

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30961326/navigation-drawer-without-actionbar-android/30961388?noredirect=1#comment49955090_30961388

Comment: It simply transparent the top of the listview . But that's not what i want. i want something like that the listview will be under the button so that if first time i click the button the drawer will be opened and if 2nd time i click the button the drawer will be closed. @Nilesh

Comment: Giving margin from doesn't make transparent it leaves that much of space

Answer (score 0):

To hide actionbar, simply do this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getSupportActionBar().hide(); 
}
```